# Не могу исправить ошибку с неразрешенным символом zlib

Tags: c++, zlib

Вот тот новый кусок кода, где появились те самые ошибки:

```
#define ZLIB_WINAPI
#include <zlib.h>

static inline char* compress_string(const char* str, int level)
{
    uLongf compressed_size = compressBound(strlen(str) + 1);
    char* compressed_data = (char*)malloc(compressed_size);

    if (compress2((Bytef*)compressed_data, &compressed_size, (const Bytef*)str, strlen(str) + 1, level) != Z_OK) {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Error compressing string.", (LPCWSTR)L"Error Details", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        free(compressed_data);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return compressed_data;
}
```

Ошибки при сборке программы такие:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ compress2 в
> функции "char * __cdecl compress_string(char const *,int)"
> (?compress_string@@YAPEADPEBDH@Z).

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ compressBound в
> функции "char * __cdecl compress_string(char const *,int)"
> (?compress_string@@YAPEADPEBDH@Z).

В свойствах проекта я указал компоновщику на zlib.lib, архитектура проекта установлена на x64. Эта библиотека и в x86 есть. Но все равно не может найти. Я уже компоновщику и в дополнительные библиотеки ссылку прямую кидал на lib файлы, все те же ошибки...

Comment: Убедитесь, что линкуемая библиотека была собрана совместимо с `ZLIB_WINAPI` (проверьте экспортируемые там символы), ну или без этой директивы попробуйте собрать.

Comment: @user7860670 получилось!!! Спасибо большое, достаточно было убрать ZLIB_WINAPI